# eBay API maximum price filter not working

Tags: url, filter, criteria, ebay-api

Having a weird issue with the eBay API: can anyone explain to me why this URL doesn't work?

It returns an item with a priced at $1,800,000 even though I am setting the `MaxPrice` as $100,000.

```json
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1
  ?SECURITY-APPNAME=*MYAPIKEY*
  &OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords
  &SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
  &RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON
  &REST-PAYLOAD
  &paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20
  &itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice
  &itemFilter(0).value=100000
  &itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency
  &itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD
  &itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice
  &itemFilter(2).value=20000
  &itemFilter(3).paramName=Currency
  &itemFilter(3).paramValue=USD
  &itemFilter(4).name=ListingType
  &itemFilter(4).value=FixedPrice
  &keywords=gtr
  &buyerPostalCode=10598
  &itemFilter.name=MaxDistance
  &itemFilter.value=250
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be indexing your itemFilter before getting all the attributes for each price parameter assigned properly. That is, your MaxPrice, for example, is defined thus:

```
&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice
&itemFilter(0).value=100000
&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency
&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD
```

Per the eBay API documentation, all four of the elements above should be in the same indexed element (&itemFilter(0) in this case, not &itemFilter(1)). Their example demonstrates assigning all four values to itemFilter(0), like this:

```
&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice
&itemFilter(0).value=25
&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency
&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD
```

Same problem with the MinPrice limit later on in your code.

It appears that in the results you describe, the price ranges are being ignored as being incomplete, and the retrieval is based only on the other parameters you passed in for ZIP code and MaxDistance.

Ref: [eBay API Making a Call](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html)